# In the following figure prove that: $OA\bot B'C'$

Tags: euclidean-geometry

> In the following figure prove that: $OA$ is perpendicular to $B'C'$
>   ($ABC$ is an arbitrary triangle,$BB'$ and $CC'$ are heights and $O$ is circumcenter)
>   [image]

I noticed that $B,C',B',C$ are concyclic, but how does this fact help?(another set of 4 concyclic points is also seen in the figure)

Comment: You may use the fact that $O$ and $H$ are isogonal conjugates and $BCB'C'$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. Since $AH\perp BC$, $AO\perp B'C'$ follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construction:- 1) Join OB; 2) Drop a perpendicular from O to AB.

[image]

$\angle 1 = \angle 2$ [congruent triangles]

$\angle 1 + \angle 2 = 2 \times \angle 3$ [Angle at center = 2 times angle at circumference]

$\angle 3 = \angle 4$ [exterior angle of cyclic quad.].

Result follows.

Added:
[image]

Comment: Please explain more( worth +1)

Comment: How can we deduce that $OA$ is perpendicular to $B'C'$?

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi $\angle 1 = \angle 4$ means there is a black dotted circle. After we got the black dotted circle, we can conclude that the required angle is equal to the marked right angle, See added.

Answer (score 0):

assume the circle centered at the origin $O(0, 0)$ & the coordinates $A(x_1, y_1)$, $B(x_2, y_2)$ & $C(x_3, y_3)$ then find the coordinates of foots of perpendiculars $B'$ & $C'$ & then find out slope of line B'C' & line OA then show the product of slope to be $-1$

Comment: A classical geometric solution is preferred rather than analytic geometry

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a geometrical proof:

Let J be the point where AO intersects C'B'

Assume B'BC=x

Then B'CB=90-x and hence AOB=180-2x (why?)

B'C'C= x

Hence B'C'A=90-X (why?)

Look at ΔAOB : AO=OB hence it is isosceles and then we have BAO=x.

Now look at ΔAJC where C'AO=x and AC'B' = 90-x.

Thus AJC=90 .

Comment: I hope you can figure out the reasons behind some steps since they follow from basic geometrical lemmas.